# Symfony3 logger as a service

Tags: symfony, logging, service

I have custom class in my symfony application and I am trying to implement the logger in it, but without success. I have tryed to made a service like this :

```
#in app/config/services.yml
services:
    ControlLib.logger.monolog:
        class: My\TestBundle\Lib\ControlsLib
        arguments: ["@logger"] 
        tags:
            - { name: monolog.logger}

#in My/TestBundle/Lib/ControlsLib
class ControlsLib { 
 private $logger;

 public function __construct(LoggerInterface $logger    ) {
    $this->logger = $logger;
 }

 public function mainControl() {
     $this->logger->info(var_export('In my lib',true));
 }
}
```

I have this message when I call my function

```
Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to 
My\TestBundle\Lib\ControlsLib::__construct() must be an instance of 
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Log\LoggerInterface, none given
```

Comment: Can you access @logger service in a controller ?

Comment: In a controller I just use $this->get('logger')->info(var_export('test',true)) and it's worked

Comment: controllib.logger.monolog should be lowercase, tested your code and it works.

Comment: I change it to lower case, but it still doesn't work for me. I have the same error in __construct() of ControlsLib. I think I missed somthing.

Comment: Answered, but it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tested your code and it works as expected:

AppBundle/Lib/ControlsLib.php:

```
namespace AppBundle\Lib;

use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class ControlsLib
{
    private $logger;

    public function __construct(LoggerInterface $logger)
    {
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    public function mainControl()
    {
        $this->logger->info(var_export('In my lib',true));
    }
}
```

app/config/services.yml:

```
services:
    controllib.logger.monolog:
        class: AppBundle\Lib\ControlsLib
        arguments: ["@logger"]
        tags:
            - { name: monolog.logger}
```

AppBundle/Controller/AppController.php:

```
$this->get('controllib.logger.monolog')->mainControl();
dump($this->get('controllib.logger.monolog')); die();
```

```text
AppController.php on line 32:
ControlsLib {#108 ▼
  -logger: Logger {#107 ▼
    #name: "app"
    #handlers: array:2 [▶]
    #processors: array:2 [▶]
    #microsecondTimestamps: true
  }
}
```

Note that you service name should be lower-case as symfony will lower-case it automatically.

Comment: is it the services file of the bundle or of the app?

Comment: I have exactly the same, but still the error with construct. I don't understand the part in AppBundle/Controller/AppController.php, I didn't have this

Comment: Weird, try removing the "tags" part of the service.

Comment: Still the problem "Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to My\TestBundle\Lib\ControlsLib::__construct() must implement interface Psr\Log\LoggerInterface, none given".

Comment: Can"t do more sorry. Delete an rewrite your service definition. Try another class...

Comment: I have another idea. The function dump($this->get('controllib.logger.monolog')); works in my controller I think the problem is maybe the call of my ControlsLib. I did it like this :$ControlsLib = new ControlsLib(); and then $ControlsLib->mainControl();

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139971/discussion-between-coil-and-etienne).